# "Generate method" option appears at the end of options when implementing an event handler in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2022

I searched around but couldn't find anything online discussing this - perhaps I didn't use the right search terms.

When assigning an event handler to a method which hasn't yet been declared, Visual Studio 2019 and earlier provided a really handy shortcut for implementing the missing method.

For example, if my `page` instance has an `Appearing` event, then I could type the following in Visual Studio:

```
page.Appearing += HandleAppearing
```

Pressing CTRL+period resulted in the suggestion to "Generate method HandleAppearing"

[image]

This is so common and handy that I have developed muscle memory on this feature over the years.

But Visual Studio 2022 has changed everything!

[image]

Now I have to select the 6th option, passing by 5 other options that I *never* select. Why has this changed? Is there a way to revert it back?

Comment: In VS 2022, you just press TAB (after you have entered `=`, you should see a tooltip appear)

Comment: You could also send feedback to the product team through VS.  It is probably an oversight that the order changed.